# Configuring keyboard with script to run at login

Tags: bash, keyboard

There are two changes to the keyboard behaviour I want to implement: 1) setting CAPS LOCK to Control and 2) decreasing the time it takes for a character to be inserted once I press down a key.

I can achieve that by running the following commands on a terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps
xset r rate 200 80
```

I'd like, however, to have these changes effective every time I log in without any extra action from my side.

I have tried adding the file to `/etc/profile.d/keyboard_config.sh` with the commands above. But it didn't work.

I also wouldn't like to download an extra tool only for that.

Is there a way I can accomplish that with only a script? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your commands into a shell script, and have it started from a `.desktop` file under `~/.config/autostart`.

Or click on "Activities" in the lower left corner, and search for "Startup Applications". There you can also add your script. (it's just an interface that will write a .desktop file into the autostart directory)